# Does this inequality hold for all N?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Assume when $ N > 0, N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_{i}, k$ satisfies

1. $\sum_{i}^{N} x_{i}=0\quad (x_{i}\in \mathbb{R})$
2. $k \geq1\quad \left(k \in \mathbb{R}\right)$
3. $kx_{i} \geq -{{1}\over{N}}$

When above assumptions satisfied, does this inequality holds?

$$\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left(x_{i}+{{1}\over{N}}\right) \geq \prod_{i=1}^{N}\left(kx_{i}+{{1}\over{N}}\right)$$

I tried to prove above inequality, and I could show it holds when $N=1,2$.

Then I tried to use mathematical induction but I failed.

Comment: Hint: Jensen’s on $\log((1/N+kx)/(1/N+x))$

Comment: Thanks for your HINT !